# if it is possible to make an orderByChild and equal to to get these tags?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wonder if it is possible to make an orderByChild and equal to to get these tags?

Json data:

```
    {
      "Bots" : {
        "1" : {
          "120" : {
            "2" : {
              "votes" : -1
            }
          },
          "avatar" : "https://discordapp.com/assets/f78426a064bc9dd24847519259bc42af.png",
          "bot" : "1",
          "bot_invite" : "651207307308302382",
          "created_at" : "2",
          "guilds_count" : "NA",
          "library" : "discljord",
          "long_description" : "\n651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382651207307308302382",
          "name" : "Clyde",
          "nsfw" : "false",
          "other_owners" : "",
          "owner" : "463696108766494730",
          "owner_avatar" : "5649a972af8d7296c2b5229252252119",
          "owner_discriminator" : "9205",
          "owner_name" : "Bruninho",
          "prefix" : "651207307308302382",
          "server_invite" : "651207307308302382",
          "short_description" : "65120730730830238265120730730830238265120730730830238265120730730830238265120730730830238265120730730830238265120730730830238265120730730830",
          "status" : "Awaiting review",
          "

tags" : {
        "anime" : {
          "tags" : true
        },
        "image" : {
          "tags" : true
        },
        "moderation" : {
          "tags" : true
        }
      },
      "vote_month" : -1,
      "votes" : -1,
      "website" : "651207307308302382"
    },
    }
```

Example: a user will search for a tag, the app will check all Users Items in my database, place an orderByChild on the tags and equalTo the user's value

Currrent Code,but i can't get the item event if it has the tag

```
   database
.ref("Bots/").orderByChild("tags").equalTo(`${req.params.tag}`)
.once("value", function(snapshot) {
          console.log(snapshot.val())
      res.render("tag", { data:snapshot.val(), url: disc_url,status:status,tag:tag  });

})
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: It would be nice if you removed most of the attributes that are unrelated to your question. You're mentioning a `Users` "Items", but there is no `Users` in your JSON. You haven't shown us what the value of `req.params.tag` is (I'm assuming `"anime"` etc.). Why are you using `anime: { tags: true }` instead of `anime: true`?

Comment: O yes,sorry but req.params.tag is an express param,so like: someurl.com/tag/anime. The req.params.tag should be "anime". I am not using anime: true,cause If U need to see ur database 
it will occupy a very large size and will be more confused than it already is, separating it in the shape of a child is easier to find errors or fix things

Comment: @BrunoGod If you're asking about Firebase, assume we don't care about the Express bits. If you're asking about Express, assume we don't care about the Firebase bits. In other words: reproduce the problem with as few technologies as possible, trying to use hard-coded values and `console.log` statements only. That makes it much easier (and thus more likely) that someone can help.

Comment: Aside from that, I think you're trying to filter by category, which is not ideal in your current data structure. For more on why that is, and a better solution, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value